# XML ZohoCreator filter by Date

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have i request that i'm executing but it does not return the result filter ! i would like your opinion !

```
$xmlData = '<ZohoCreator>
                            <application name="ecoute">
                                    <form name="'.$formulaire.'">
                                        <criteria>
                                          <field name="ID" compOperator="Equals" value="'.$conseillerID.'"></field>
                                                <reloperator>AND</reloperator>
                                          <field name="Concessionnaire" compOperator="Equals" value="'.$concessionnaire.'"></field>
                                          <field name="Added_Time" compOperator="GreaterThan" value="'.$dateDebut->format('d-M-Y H:i:s').'"></field>
                                                <reloperator>AND</reloperator> 
                                          <field name="Added_Time" compOperator="LessThan" value="'.$dateFin->format('d-M-Y H:i:s').'"></field> 
                                        </criteria>                                                                   
                                    </form>
                            </application>
                    </ZohoCreator>';
```

My question is that if i can't do it this way, might it be an easyer way with xpath that i do use like :

```
$Column = $feed->xpath('//record/column[@name="'.$champRecherche.'"]/value');///descendant::*');
```

here's an example of what i tried but it doesn't work as well so dont judge on this it was just a try !! :

```
$filter = $feed->xpath('//record/column[@name="'.$nomChampDate.'"]/value[date( >= "'.$dateDebut->format('d-m-Y').'" and @name="'.$nomChampDate.'" <= "'.$dateFin->format('d-m-Y'))]');
```

the problem is that i didn't use xpath that mutch so how can i filter the date with it ?

here is an example of return that i receive :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
<form name="Conseillers">
<criteria>
    <field name="ID" compOperator="Equals" value="1111111111111"></field>
</criteria>
<records>
<record>
    <column name="Modified_User_IP_Address">

        <value><![CDATA[192.168.0.1]]></value>        
    </column>
            <column name="Added_User_IP_Address">

                <value><![CDATA[192.168.0.1]]></value>                
            </column>
                    <column name="Added_User">

                        <value><![CDATA[123456]]></value>                        
                    </column>
                            <column name="Added_Time">

                                <value><![CDATA[28-Mar-2013 11:07:54]]></value>                                
                            </column>
```

Comment: If you generate xml as a string, you have to escape the values you insert. Use `htmlspecialchars()`. A better approach would be to create the XML using DOM. You XML example does not contain record or column elements. Attributes a marked in xpath with @ so use @value.

Comment: hi ! this is a example that i need to follow to be able to recover data but i forgot the return example i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with DOMXpath:evaluate(), SimpleXMLElement::xpath() not return scalars.

Fetch the record/column elements:

`//record/column`

Filter them using the name attribute:

`//records/column[@name="Added_User_IP_Address"]`

Get the value child elements:

`//record/column[@name="Added_User_IP_Address"]/value`

Cast the first found node to string (return all text content), without that it would return a node list.

`string(//record/column[@name="Added_User_IP_Address"]/value)`

Full Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
  <form name="Conseillers">
    <records>
      <record>
        <column name="Modified_User_IP_Address">
          <value><![CDATA[192.168.0.1]]></value>        
        </column>
        <column name="Added_User_IP_Address">
          <value><![CDATA[192.168.0.1]]></value>                
        </column>
      </record>
    </records>
  </form>
</response>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//record/column[@name="Added_User_IP_Address"]/value)')
);
```

Output:

```
string(11) "192.168.0.1"
```